# How to prevent a man-in-the-middle attack in case of a compromised server?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key

Imagine that a server is serving public keys of the users to their partners to make encrypted communication possible. However, the server does NOT have access to the private keys..

Anyway - imagine the server is hacked and it sends not the requested public keys:

> Alice requests Bob's public key
>       Server sends **Eve's** public key
>
> Bob requests Alice's public key
>       Server sends **Eve's** public key
>
> Alice sends a message to Bob
>       Server unpacks message, reads it and repacks it -> sends to Bob...
>
> Bob sends a message to Alice
>       Server unpacks message, reads it and repacks it -> sends to Alice...

My question is - how to prevent such abuse? How can Alice be sure that she's using Bob's public key and vice versa?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under the scheme you just proposed, you can't. The key here (no pun intended) is if the method used to verify the validity of the keys is compromised, you lose.

SSL tries to avoid this by creating a signature chain - some (very carefully guarded, and verified by other methods) key signs another key, signs another key, signs Alice's key. By verifying each step in the chain you can (in principle) know that the chain is valid - but if the private key along any step in the chain is compromised, you lose.

PGP (aka GPG) tries to solve the problem in a different, but similar way - keys can be signed by any number of other keys, forming a graph (called the [web of trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust)). You select some keys that you have confirmed valid by, for example, verifying them *in person*, and mark them as trusted. Then any keys reachable by less than N steps (and/or from M distinct paths from different trusted roots) are also considered valid.

If you're really paranoid, you can, of course, physically hand the key to the other person. Of course, they have to be sure it's not someone disguised as you...

That said, the only truly foolproof way of verifying the validity of a key is generating it yourself... unless your hardware/OS/compiler/brain is compromised too :)

Comment: In this case, you could have Alice and Bob's public keys be distributed as certificates, signed by a trusted third party (traditionally called Trent).  Trent's public key is known to everybody ahead of time (eg. distributed with the software), and the server doesn't know Trent's private key either, so it can't forge certificates.  Trent's private key only comes into play when a new user is added into the system, so it can be kept completely offline.

Comment: Sure, but now the problem is, what if Trent's key is compromised?

Comment: It's turtles all the way down! (Which is a tongue-in-cheek way of saying: Yes, that's a concern.  It is, however, easier to secure Trent's private key than the key distribution server, since the former may be kept offline - or even destroyed, if you never want to add new users - whereas the latter has to be online).

Answer (score 3):

The crucial part missing here is *authentication*. Alice needs a way to know that she is really using Bobs public key. One way would be to exchange the keys personally but that is not always possible.

That is what the [Web of Trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) is for. Other parties can sign the public key of a user if they are sure that this key belongs to him. If enough (3) of your other contacts (which you trust) signed the public key of Bob, you can be relatively sure that it is his key.

Answer (score 0):

This is the primary problem with public key encryption.  You don't have any way to verify that the public key you receive is actually the public key for your intended recipient.  The way HTTPS/SSL gets around this is through the use of trusted certificate authorities.  The certificate authority signs the public key of the party in question with their private key, guaranteeing that the public key hasn't been changed since it was provided to the certificate authority.  Even then, it is only guaranteed that the key provided to you when you request it is the same key that was originally provided to the certificate authority.  However, if the server providing those certificates is compromised, you're still in trouble.  Even having the server sign the keys as suggested above isn't fool proof if the sever itself is compromised.  Ultimately, the security if your key distribution server must be maintained for this system to work.

Answer (score 0):

The [FAQ for PGP (Pretty Good Privacy)](http://www.pgpi.org/doc/pgpintro/) explains this issue.

I would also recommend reading Bruce Schneier's excellent book "[Applied Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html)" for "friendly and digestible" discussions of these topics.