# Consuming HTTPS web service using WCF

Tags: web-services, wcf, configuration, https, fortify

I'm trying to consuming a client's web service using WCF. The client's web service is done over HTTPS, and I can consume it fine with the following Binding:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="PurchaseOrderSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

However, our security team have told me I need to use `Message` or `TransportWithMessageCredential` security, because Fortify 360 complains that `Transport` security is too weak.

When I try `Meesage` I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: BasicHttp binding requires that 
BasicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType be equivalent to the 
BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate credential type for secure messages. Select 
Transport or TransportWithMessageCredential security for UserName credentials.
```

And with `TransportWithMessageCredential` I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The username is not provided. Specify username in 
ClientCredentials.
```

I've not got a username/password (I can connect to it fine in my browser), so my question is:

Can I use `Message` or `TransportWithMessageCredentials` when consuming an existing HTTPS web service (without the publisher  making any changes)? If so, what changes do I need to make to my configuration?

Edited to clarify question.

Comment: Are you negotiating with the client on what to expose? If they are not using message security, nothing you can do on the client side about it. Both ends must agree on the security policy.

Comment: @tomasr: It's a web service that lots of people currently use, so there's no scope for changing it's current behaviour. I'll change the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot get the third party vendor to add an endpoint to their service that supports message security then you are stuck. It seems they currently only support basicHttpBinding with transport level security.

Transport security is not "less" secure than message level security. Message level security means the contents of the soap message are encrypted. This allows you to either store or relay a message in a clear text way and still be assured no one can peek at the message. If all you are doing is communicating between your system and the vendor over the internet then transport and message level security are equally secure.

Comment: According to Fortify 360: `Transport security specifies that confidentiality, integrity, and authentication are provided by transport-layer mechanisms (such as HTTPS). When using a transport like HTTPS, this mode has the advantage of being efficient in its performance and well understood because of its prevalence on the Internet. The disadvantage is that this kind of security is applied separately on each hop in the communication path, making the communication susceptible to a "man in the middle" attack.` So it's the lackof authentication that's the problem.

Comment: Theoretically, it is possible to apply to a "man in the middle" attack to any SSL (HTTPS) based connection. Message based encryption is also vulnerable to an attack that successfully comprises the certificate like it happened to RSA recently. The point is all encryption methods will have some vulnerability even if an attack strategy hasn't been determined yet. Security is about minimizing risk. SSL is perfectly acceptable for all public ecommerce on the internet today so it provides a reasonable level of security, especially given that you can't change the 3rd party service configuration.

Comment: Thanks! For more info on man in the middle attacks, here is an answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591342

Answer (score 1):

The basicHttpBinding only supports username and certificate message security. So one option is, if you don't have a mechanism for validating user credentials on your sysstem, is to use certificates.

```
<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    ...
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
</security>
```

The other option is to use a different binding, like wsHttpBinding which has message security enabled by default and also supports Windows and Issued Token credential types. Which of these you implement is largely dependent on your implementation requirements and environment.

Comment: I don't have any credentials to use, and seeing as the client is not under my control (and cannot change due to other users), I don't think I can use the code you provided. Can I use certificates without any changes on the client side?

Comment: @Jackson Pope: Not being able to make any changes to your client will limit your alternatives. I think @Sixto is right. Transport security is acceptable for most instances. If the channel is compromised it will corrupt the message at any rate making it useless.

Answer (score 1):

Do you not have some sort of exception policy by which you can take a note of why it's impossible to implement Fortify's best recommendation?

I would think the best you can do is communicate with your webservice vendor and ask for an enhancement to support Fortify's transport guidelines.

Also: I'm suspicious that you say the web browser connects you without a credential. This probably means the system you are connecting to is a little more complex than your assumptions. different connections or different urls may be served by different servers (SSO?) or may be subject to different security policies (client certificate, etc)